# Copying values / columns from one table to another existing tabler in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, database, ssms

I want to copy all columns from `dbo.die` to `dbo.technology`.

Both tables exist! In `dbo.technology`, the primary key is `idTechnology`

In `dbo.die`, the primary key is `idDie` and we have a foreign key, which is `Technology_idTechnology` in it, which connects the die table with the technology table.

How could I do that, so that the values got copied to the right rows, which match the same `idTechnology`?

I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.die 
(Technology_idTechnology, Technology_D, Technology_Type, Technology_Manufacturer, Technology_SOI, Technology_Node, Technology_Name, Technology_Number_Metal, Technology_Number_Poly, Technology_Power_Cu, Technology_FEComplexity, Technology_FEComplexity_Sec, Technology_Trench, Technology_IMID, Technology_Remarks)
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.technology tech
    WHERE tech.idTechnology = idTechnology;
```

but I'm always getting an error!

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.die' with unique index 'ui_dieIdsample'. The duplicate key value is ().

Don't know what I should do.. I thought it's easy & simple

Comment: Don't tag products not involved. (Are you using both MySQL and MS SQL Server here?

Comment: What is the complete table structure of your two database tables? @zelelb

Answer (score 0):

If a column is declared as `NOT NULL` (and has no default value), a value for the column must be specified in the `INSERT` statement.

In this specific case you should add `Table2_Feld` to the insert column list, and specify a value in the `SELECT` for it!

Comment: yeah but is my sql statement "apart of that" right to copy the columns and its values to the other existing table?

Comment: If you don't specify the column on your INSERT statement, then only the DEFAULT value is used.  Since you have no DEFAULT, NULL is used, and since the column is defined with "NOT NULL", you get the error.

Comment: i did that now, but it still not copying the data.. the columns are there, but no content.. no values in the columns.. i want that if the Table1_idTech is gleich wie der idTech in table1, the values get copied in the table 2

Comment: You're obviously trying to insert a duplicate value, but a unique index stops you. Which column(s) is included in the ui_dieIdsample index?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your column list (lets say that its acceptable to insert a default value of 0 into column Table2_Feld)

```
    INSERT INTO dbo.table2  
    (Table1_idTech, Tech_D, Techn_Type, Tech_Man,             
 Techn_Node, Tech_Name, Technology_Numb, Tech_Po,  
Tech_FEC, Techn_Comp_Sec, 
Tech_R,Table2_Feld)
     select *,0 from  table1 tech
```

Comment: how will be the data copied in the right rows? because table1 and table2 are connected through that idTech, and you have in the statement no "where" or something else..

Comment: When you insert you are creating new rows. Are you trying to update rows or insert rows?

Comment: update.. i inserted the columns manually, and they are empty now... but if there s a solution to copy the columns + the values, then i will delete the columns and copy everything.. not just the headers (column names) which i did til now..

Comment: I still see an insert as the first part of the statement. Inserts creates new rows, updates changes existing rows.

Comment: ok, now i deleted the columns i added to the table, to which i want to copy the data. So back to the beginning. 

I have table dbo.die, and table dbo.technology! dbo.die is related to dbo.technology with the foreign-key Technology_idTechnology.

I want now to copy all the columns/values of dbo.technology to dbo.die! Of course, the data should be copied when the Technology_idTechnology in table dbo.die is the same (idTechnology) in the table dbo.technology! 

What should I do?

Comment: anyone could help please?